# JPA/EclipseLink - Undesirable Foreign Key created during table create/update on startup

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have the following `@Entity` classes

```
@Entity
public class Asset {

  @Id
  private long id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private TagType tagType;

  private String tagId;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumns(value = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "tagId", referencedColumnName = "tagId", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "tagType", referencedColumnName = "tagType", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)})
  private TagInfo tagInfo;

  ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class TagInfo {

    @Id
    private String tagId

    @Id
    private TagType tagType

    ...     
}
```

When EclipseLink start using `"eclipselink.ddl-generation" = "drop-and-create-tables"`, it creates the `ASSET` table with the following constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_ASSET_TAGTYPE FOREIGN KEY(TAGTYPE,TAGID) REFERENCES TAGINFO(TAGTYPE,TAGID))
```

Is there anyway to have EclipseLink **NOT** create the above constraint on the `Asset` table?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid this constraint? It makes sure your data are coherent.

Comment: With the above constraint, when I insert an Asset with tagId and tagType (no corresponding tagId/tagType entry for TagInfo), it throws "Integrity constraint violation - no parent FK_ASSET_TAGTYPE". This is not the desire behavior. Basically I would like the ability to have a left join of Asset and TagInfo so Asset can exist with or without TagInfo.